# Image Classification using python api for Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have classified (supervised classification) sentinel-2 optical imagery using google earth engine java-script api. In one project i have also used python api of Google earth engine for calculation indices NDVI, EVI etc. Now i want to use the same(google earth engine python api) for image classification. But i am unable to figure out how i can provide training sets for classification from earth engine python api. Is it possible to save the training points in fusion table and use that for training in python api for GEE? or is there any other way to do the same.
Advance thanks for your assistence.

Answer (score 2):

You can export to KML (`Export.table.toDrive()`), then upload to Fusion Table or export to Earth Engine asset (`Export.table.toAsset()`) and read it directly from there.